# C++ dynamic array assignment error heap[0]=heap[length-1] Error

Tags: arrays, netbeans, dynamic, segmentation-fault, variable-assignment

i am implementing a minmax heap with c++ in netbeans, but i get a strange error. Somebody help, thanks!
the statement heap[0]=heap[length-1]; get an segment error, but i can access both the element at 0 and (length-1).

```
int MinMaxHeap::deleteMin(){
assert(length>0);
int min= heap[0];
heap[0]=heap[length-1];
length--;

int id=0,gid=4*id+3;
while(gid<length){
    int i,cmin=heap[gid],cmin_idx=gid;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(gid>(length-1))
            break;
        if(heap[gid]<cmin){
            cmin=heap[gid];
            cmin_idx=gid;
        }
        gid++;
    }
    swap(heap[id],heap[cmin_idx]);
    id=cmin_idx;
    gid=4*id+3;
}
int sid1=2*id+1,sid2=sid1+1,cmin,cmin_idx;
if(sid1<length){
    cmin=heap[sid1];
    cmin_idx=sid1;
    if(sid2<length){
        if(heap[sid2]<heap[sid1]){
            cmin=heap[sid2];
            cmin_idx=sid2;
        }
    }
    if(heap[id]>cmin)
        swap(heap[id],heap[cmin_idx]);
}

return min;
```

}

the class declaration is:

```
class MinMaxHeap {

public:

    MinMaxHeap(int size);

    virtual ~MinMaxHeap();

    int findMin();
    int findMax();
    int deleteMin();
    int deleteMax();
    bool insert(int x);
private:

    int getLevel(int i); //get the level of the ith element

    void swap(int&,int&);
    int length;  //current no. of elements of heap
    int size;    //heap size
    int *heap;   //the heap array
};
```

Comment: did you `new` or `malloc` the heap?

Comment: It might be related to how `heap` is initialized - could we see you constructor code?

Comment: Where are you allocating `heap`?

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLinde  `MinMaxHeap::MinMaxHeap(int size=10) {
    this->size=size;
    heap=new int[this->size];
    this->length=0;
}`

Comment: We're really going to have to see what you're doing. Length is `0` at that point. Where does that change?

Comment: @Brian Roach i've inerted 11 elements, so length is not 0

Comment: Try adding `assert( length <= size )` at the top to verify you haven't overrun the buffer.

Comment: if i print heap[0] and heap[length-1], i can get the right value, but i cannot assign to heap[0],even `heap[0]=30;`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the destructor for the class is being called sometime before the call to `deleteMin`.  Do you ever pass the instance of `MinMaxHeap` by value?  That would trigger the destructor and, assuming you delete `heap` in the destructor, the heap would be invalid.

Comment: no, even if i do nothing in the destructor, it is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

MinMaxHeap contains a pointer member, but has no copy constructor。 
In case, when copy constructor is needed, MinMaxHeap will invoke default copy constructor and pointer are value copied. When any one of copy of a instance was destroyed, all copy become invalid.

Some examples of copy constructor are invoked as below:

```
1. void fun(MinMaxHeap m); 
2. std::vector<MinMaxHeap> vecM; //containers
   vecM.push_back(MinMaxHeap(5));
3. MinMaxHeap A(5);
   MinMaxHeap aliasA = A;
```

Usually, you invoke copy constructor unintentionally. So check your code carefully or implement a copy constructor and try again.

Comment: thanks, maybe something is wrong with netbeans, i run my code under gcc, nothing is wrong.